# How do i read a Json as a string or dictionary from a Column in spark dataframe using pyspark and without using RDD or collect()?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe that looks like this,

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                     output|
+-------------------------------------------+
|{"COLUMN1": "123", "COUMN2": {"A":1 "B":2}}|
+-------------------------------------------+
```

And i just want to read the json as a string or dictionary in a variable so that i could do further manipulations on it.

Problems are -

- Apparently when you use unity catalogue on databricks you are not allowed to use rdd's or methods like .iterrows,.collect,etc. (ref - https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009yKdeHSAS/cannot-use-rdd-and-cannot-set-sparkdatabrickspysparkenablepy4jsecurity-false-for-cluster)
- And using something like .asDict or .first() is converting into Rows datatype and am not able to convert it back into json.
  EG.

```
Row(output=Row(COLUMN1='123', ...
```

How was the df created ?

```
nextdf = df.select(struct(col("COLUMN1"),col("COLUMN2"),col("COLUMN3")).alias("output"))
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE -
`{"COLUMN1": "123", "COUMN2": {"A":1 "B":2}}`

Please let me know what can i try ?

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Image is required , so that people can see how the df looks like. Otherwise they won't get the clear idea

Comment: Can you add your input and expected output in textual format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`toJSON()`** for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo"),(2, "bar"),],["id", "label"])

df1= df.withColumn("temp", concat_ws(" ", *df.columns)).groupBy(lit(1)).agg(array_join(collect_list(col("temp"))," ").alias("new_column")).drop("1")

print(df1.select(struct(col("new_column")).alias("new")).toJSON().collect()[0])
#{"new":{"new_column":"1 foo 2 bar"}}
```

---

To get things without collecting then use

**`Save as Text:`**

Use **`save`** as **`text`** file with **`header`** flag `false` to escape the column name from the output file.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("text").option("header", "false").save("output.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

`RDD` is the old interface, `DataFrame` is the new/replacement interface. Use `DataFrame` methods.

```py
my_var = nextdf.collect()[0].asDict()['output']
print(my_var)
# should print `{"COLUMN1": "123", "COUMN2": {"A":1 "B":2}}`
```